# Swipe to delete UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a "swipe to delete" in the `UITableViewCell`. I tried the following code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?
{
    var delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Delete", handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPath, withRowAnimation: .Automatic) // Error
    })
}
```

But I get the following error at the line of creating the `delete rowAction`

> Could not find member 'Normal'

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

**Update 1**

I tried `UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal` as @rmaddy pointed out.

but got the following error:

```
Cannot find an initializer for type 'UITableViewRowAction' that accepts an argument list of type '(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle, title: String, handler: (UITableViewRowAction!, NSIndexPath!) -> Void)'
```

I had this after the `delete var`, and it didn't give me an error. It works fine:

```
var action = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "action", handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        println("Action")
})
```

**Update 2**

Just realized the problem. When I insert the following action:

```
self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPath, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

I get the error. When I remove that line, the error goes away.

Comment: Try `UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal`.

Comment: I updated the questin

Comment: Try renaming the `delete` variable to `del` or something else (and go back to just `.Normal`.

Comment: I just copied and pasted the `action var`, and renamed it to delete, and it finally works! Not sure what went wrong. Btw, is it wrong to delete a cell in `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` and not in `commitEditingStyle`?

Comment: check my update code @Jessica

Comment: They are two completely different methods. `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` simply lets you define what appears on a left swipe of the cell. The `commitEditStyle` method is where you actual perform an action.

Comment: @rmaddy But it has an option to add an action i.e, `handler`?

Comment: Right, sorry. Use the handler to support the action. Use `commitEditingStyle:` if you need to support the standard "insert" and "delete" functionality provided by `UITableView`.

Comment: I updated my question again

Comment: @Jessica look at my update answer

Comment: Why can't I just use `handler` for everything? Isn't it simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPath, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

TO **because that method is expecting an array of indexPath**

```
self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

Comment: Please read the question again. The OP has this method and it has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: but he wants to swipe and delete cells @rmaddy

Comment: The question is about the compiler error, not the implementation of the `commitEditingStyle:` method.

Comment: What's the difference of inserting it in `commitEditingStyle` vs `editActionsForRow...`?

Comment: @rmaddy it does not matter if implement the commitEditingStyle The OP wants to delete cell that method also work

Comment: @Lamar I think you are missing the point here. What is the question about? It's about the compiler error in the line of code in the `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` method. How does your answer fix that issue? The `commitEditingStyle` method is completely unrelated to the compiler error (and the immediate question).

Comment: @rmaddy its weird that the normal method is not working , i guess Jessica should use the the Default method

Comment: @Lamar Thanks! I changed `indexPath` to `[indexPath]` and the error went away. It's a very unclear error!

Comment: its because the method is expecting and array of object, not a single variable

Comment: Is it wrong to put that in the handler as opposed to the `commitEditingStyle ` method?

Comment: you don't need to put the handler into the commitEditingStyle method, you could do it directly into the editAcationsForRowAtIndexPath